# vuejs :: Render template using variables

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a form that allows a user to draft an SMS template. I'd like to render the SMS using a variable to generate a realistic example. For example, a user may type the following into an input box (say raw-input)

```
Dear {{context.username}}, Thank you for your contribution of value {{context.amount}}
```

And in vueJS we have defined the context variable to be used to render the example test.

```
data() {
 return {
  render_sms: "",
  context: {
    amount: "1.00",
    first_name: "John",
    last_name: "Doe",
  }
};
```

I would like to apply the context to the raw-input to generate something like this in another input box from within vueJS (don't want to call an API service for this)

```
Dear John, Thank you for your contribution of value 1.00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use template literals in the input string which can be converted to the required output. Please find the snippet for further details.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: () => ({
    custInput: 'Dear ${context.first_name}, Thank you for your contribution of value ${context.amount}',
    custOutput: '',

    context: {
      amount: "1.00",
      first_name: "John",
      last_name: "Doe",
    }
  }),
  methods: {
    convert: function() {
      this.custOutput = Function('return function(context){ return `' + this.custInput + '`}')()(this.context)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app" style="display:flex;justify-content:space-between">
  <h3>Input</h3>
  <textarea v-model="custInput"></textarea>
  <button @click="convert">Convert</button>
  <h3>Output</h3>
  <textarea v-model="custOutput"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting answer, Could you share a snippet of the template to use? I have tried   "Dear {context.first_name}, Thank you for your contribution of value {{amount}}". That doesn't work

Comment: Ah, I see CustInput is already set... Is there anyway to get rid of '${', the input string will be passed to a backend API service that will use it as a jinja template. Hence custInput has to be acceptable to Jinja

Comment: One option is to use regex to change {{ var }} => ${ var }. This seems to work "Dear ${context.first_name}, ".replace(/{{/,'${').replace("}}","}")

Comment: Since you told you dont want to pass it to api, i suggested template literals. You parse and get the string back. Send the string to backend

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the raw string with regex. See the working snippet below. The only mention is that the user will have to type {{username}} instead of {{context.username}}.

`Dear {{username}}, Thank you for your contribution of value {{amount}}`

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data(){
    return {
      raw_text: '',
      context: {
        username: 'John',
        amount: 1000
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    output_text(){
      return this.raw_text.replace(/{{\s*(\w+)\s*}}/g, (match, capt) => {
        return this.context[capt]
      })
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id='app'>
<label for='raw'>Raw input</label>
<input v-model='raw_text' type="text" id='raw' />
<label for='output'>Output</label>
<input v-model='output_text' type="text" id='output' />
</div>
```